# Parcel.js Command Line Interface error when "watch" is invoked

Tags: command-line-interface, parceljs

I am receiving the following error when attempting to watch an html file for changes, with parcel:

```
C:\Users\sjsui\Desktop\git_workshop\MoonMachineOpenSource\MoonMachine\MoonMachine2\Front\templates>parcel watch index.html
×  C:\Users\sjsui\Desktop\git_workshop\MoonMachineOpenSource\MoonMachine\MoonMachine2\Front\templates\index.html: URI malformed
at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
at HTMLAsset.addURLDependency (C:\Users\sjsui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Asset.js:93:7)
at HTMLAsset.processSingleDependency (C:\Users\sjsui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\assets\HTMLAsset.js:90:26)
at ast.walk.node (C:\Users\sjsui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\assets\HTMLAsset.js:139:43)
at traverse (C:\Users\sjsui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\posthtml\lib\api.js:105:26)
at traverse (C:\Users\sjsui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\posthtml\lib\api.js:111:5)
at traverse (C:\Users\sjsui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\posthtml\lib\api.js:105:17)
at traverse (C:\Users\sjsui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\posthtml\lib\api.js:111:5)
at traverse (C:\Users\sjsui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\posthtml\lib\api.js:105:17)
at Array.walk (C:\Users\sjsui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\posthtml\lib\api.js:39:10)
```

What should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused at the point in time where parcel traverse the html document for links to bundle. When it encounters the [templating syntax of the django framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/), it throws a fit! Here is the [github ticket](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1450) where this issue is being tracked.

Comment: I'm running into this problem and the ticket you linked to was closed. Any suggestions on how to have django render the template to html or have parcel parse django template syntax?

Comment: Not possible. try webpack instead. https://pypi.org/project/django-webpack-loader/

Comment: That’s a shame. Maybe I’ll just use es6 export modules 